# What is Computable and Operable interface in java?

Tags: java

What are `Computable` and `Operable` interfaces in Java, could anyone please explain it with example?

Comment: Where did you see those interfaces? They do not exist in Java 7. Is this homework?

Comment: Arnaud ,Thanks for reply,  yes these are part homework. Search lot on google but didn't saw related things.    is it some think Computable and Operable interfaces was a part of Java before. but no more applicable to Java7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Computable` and `Operable` APIs do not exist in Java 8 (EA).  Since Sun / Oracle have not dropped any standard Java classes or interfaces since Java 1.1, we can conclude that these two APIs don't exist in any released version of Java from 1.1 to 7.0.

If you have a specific lead on these supposed APIs, please provided them.  Otherwise, I'm inclined to believe that they are either 3rd-party classes/interfaces or they don't exist at all.